# Json or xml parsing in wordpress

Tags: xml, json, wordpress

I have a theme that use custom fields. I wanna to Do something like this

my custom field code

```
<span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true); ?> </span>
```

I have an custom field named "rate". I put IMDB id in this field like this

```
tt0068646
```

I wanna get imdb rating from www.omdbapi.com. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This small function will retrieve the result for a Movie ID request, ie, `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=VALID-MOVIE-ID`. The result is in the var `$body`:

```
function get_imdb_json( $id )
{
    $url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=$id";
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    // Parse the request
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) )//&& !isset($response['body']['error'] ) ) 
    {
        $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
        return '<pre>' . print_r( $body, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
    return false;
}
```

And an example of usage that replaces a post/page content if the URL requests `?imdb=MOVIE-ID`, ie, `http://example.com/hello-world/?imdb=tt1217209`:

```
if( !is_admin() )
{
    add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){
        if( isset( $_GET['imdb'] ) && !empty( $_GET['imdb'] ) )
        {
            if( $ok = get_imdb_json( $_GET['imdb'] ) )
                return $ok;
        }    
        return $content;
    });
}
```

And in your case, it would be a matter of:

```
echo get_imdb_json( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) );
```